# Returning HTML tags from Select query in MSSQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Consider my Select query, I m using

```
Select Convert(xml, '<b>Grand Total</b>'),
Convert(xml,'<b>'+Convert(varchar,Sum(amt))+'</b>')as Amt
From myTable
For xml path(''),type  //with and without results are same
```

Also I have more HTML tags coming from a local variable in this form:

`Set @loc_var = '<Table><TR><TD>This is some dummy Text</TD></TR></TABLE>'` and so on. The above result set is finally then gets embedded within the above HTML string in somewhere. 
But after the embedding final result contains the Select statements result as below and rest are fine, no problems. Kindly help.

**Output:**

```
   <Table><TR><TD>This is some dummy Text</TD></TR></TABLE> &lt;b&gt;Grand Total&lt;/b&gt;
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
<Table><TR><TD>This is some dummy Text</TD></TR></TABLE><b>Grand Total</b>
```

Comment: There are plenty of tools that are perfectly good at generating HTML. T-SQL isn't one of them. What's running this SQL query, and why isn't *it* capable of doing the HTML generation?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what if you want to send emails from SQL jobs ?

Answer (score 2):

Hard to find:

```
SELECT @DATA = CONCAT('<br><br>',(SELECT X ,',' From MYTABLE For XML PATH (''));
```

After select XML path in a variable use, REPLACE:

```
SELECT @DATA = REPLACE(REPLACE(@DATA,'&lt ;','<'),'&gt ;','>');--THERE IS SPACE CHARACTERS, YOU SHOULD CLEAN "&gt ;" AND "&lt ;"
```

and then you can INSERT or SELECT `@DATA`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (value INT)
INSERT INTO @temp (value)
VALUES (1),(2)

SELECT '<Table><TR><TD>This is some dummy Text</TD></TR></TABLE>' + (
   SELECT SUM(value) AS [text()]
   FROM @temp
   FOR XML PATH('b')
)
```

Output -

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
<Table><TR><TD>This is some dummy Text</TD></TR></TABLE><b>3</b>
```